# Validation of migrated data for MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm migrating a large(approx. 10GB) MySQL database(InnoDB engine).

I've figured out the migration part. Export -> `mysqldump`, Import -> `mysql`.

However, I'm trying to figure out the optimum way to validate if the migrated data is correct. I thought of the following approaches but they don't completely work for me.

1. One approach could have been using `CHECKSUM TABLE`. However, I can't use it since the target database would have data continuously written to it(from other sources) even during migration.
2. Another approach could have been using the combination of `MD5()`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, and `CONCAT`. However, that also won't work for me as some of the columns contain large `JSON` data.

So, what would be the best way to validate that the migrated data is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Do SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE from each old and new table, writing them into .csv files. Then run [diff(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) between the files, eyeball the results, and convince yourself that the new tables' rows are an appropriate superset of the old tables'.

These flat files are modest in size compared to a whole database and diff is fast enough to be practical.

Comment: I wanted to do the validation in an automated fashion so that there is no manual intervention. Something like, run some query on the source and get a hash. On the destination, once the data is migrated, run the same query. The expectation is that source and target hashes match.